# Differences between != and !== with null and underfined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some javascript that uses query selector

```
let testobj;
testobj = document.querySelector('#someobject');
```

If I write the next line as below it doesn't enter the if

```
if (testobj !== null && testobj !== 'undefined')
```

If it is written as below it does

```
if (testobj != null && testobj != 'undefined')
```

Comment: With `!=` you only need one comparison. The values `null` and `undefined` are treated the same with `!=`.

Comment: Also `.querySelector()` will never return `undefined` anyway.

Comment: Do you mean `testobj !== 'undefined'` or `testobj !== undefined`?

Comment: [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)

Comment: `if (testobj !== null && testobj !== undefined)` is equal to `if (testobj != null)`, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: `'undefined'` is not the same as the `undefined` keyword

Comment: There's no reason whatsoever in this case to worry about `undefined`. Generally however `!=` is useful because in many situations `null` and `undefined` are semantically equivalent.

Comment: @DOCTYPEHTML — They aren't. Its `!==` they are using. Anything can be NOT two different things.

Comment: @DOCTYPEHTML He is asking that it be exactly _not_ two different values which is possible.  For example, 2 is not 3 and 2 is also not 4.

Comment: ==/!= checks value only, ===/!== checks value and type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using !== for undefined you should not put it in quotes.
So the code should look like:

```
if(testobj !== undefined)
```

Or you can use `typeof` to compare the quoted 'undefined', like this:

```
if(typeof testobj !== 'undefined')
```

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing two conventions for comparison with undefined:

```
 x === undefined
```

and

```
 typeof x === 'undefined'
```

Thee former used to be considered poor style because `undefined` was simply a variable, which when used before initialization had the *value* `undefined`, which could however be changed to anything, including `null` or even `3`. With modern JS that's much less of a worry - `undefined` is now non-writeable, meaning you only really need to worry about the value of `undefined` inside of everyone's favorite JavaScript bugbear, `with` blocks.

For backwards compatibility, sometimes `typeof x === 'undefined'` is preferred, but in modern practice `x === undefined` is fine. However, if you are comparing `x` against both `null` and `undefined`, `x != null` is IMO clearer and more concise, although some people do advocate never using `==` and `!=` in JavaScript.